# Solr JMX Metrics - Time Units

Tags: solr, jmx

On connecting jconsole to a Solr exposing JMX Metrics. I am seeing the below numbers:-

- requests = 10
- totalTime = 10.879355
- avgRequestsPerSecond = 0.0034740560191937196
- avgTimePerRequest = 1.0879355

Can someone please explain me the units of time in *totalTime* and *avgTimePerRequest*? Is it in seconds?

Is there any solr documentation explaining all the metrics that are exposed by solr, their meaning and their units? I have seen [SolrJMX wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJmx) and also "SolrJMX cwiki" and SolrMonitoring page under Solr wiki but none of them seem to talk about the individual metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had the same question, here's what I found looking through the source code: milliseconds.

In other places in Solr, `totalTime` is often used for values in milliseconds (see e.g. [this comment in `OfflineSorter`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5e5fd662575105de88d8514b426bccdcb4c76948/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/OfflineSorter.java#L151).

The base `RequestHandler` class uses [`requestTimes.getSum()`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5e5fd662575105de88d8514b426bccdcb4c76948/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/RequestHandlerBase.java#L268) where [`requestTimes` is a `Timer` instance with the default parameters](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5e5fd662575105de88d8514b426bccdcb4c76948/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/RequestHandlerBase.java#L61) and the [default value](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5e5fd662575105de88d8514b426bccdcb4c76948/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/util/stats/Timer.java#L40) used for [conversion in `Timer`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5e5fd662575105de88d8514b426bccdcb4c76948/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/util/stats/Timer.java#L200-L202) is milliseconds.